# Installing packages on Android SDK pointing to weird Linux packages

Tags: android, linux, installation

I am trying to install a Android 2.3.3 API 10 shown inside the SDK Manager (not some outside package whatsoever) by default.

I click accept and could not install and below is the entire log of what happened that the SDK Manager spilled out:

```
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
Validate XML
Parse XML
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-6.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-6.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-6.xml
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.1, API 2, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.0.1, API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.1, API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 2
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.1, API 12, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 14, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 2
  Found Samples for SDK API 7, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 8, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 9, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Samples for SDK API 10, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 11, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 12, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 13, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 14, revision 2
  Found Samples for SDK API 15, revision 2
  Found Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 11
  Found Android SDK Tools, revision 19
  Found Documentation for Android SDK, API 15, revision 2
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 14, revision 1
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 15, revision 2
  Found Android Support, revision 8
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Found Google APIs, Android API 3, revision 3
  Found Google APIs, Android API 4, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 7, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 8, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 10, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 11, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 12, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 13, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 14, revision 2
  Found Google TV Addon, Android API 12, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 15, revision 2
  Found Google Play Licensing Library, revision 2
  Found Google Play APK Expansion Library, revision 1
  Found Google USB Driver, revision 4
  Found Google Play Billing Library, revision 1
  Found Google AdMob Ads SDK, revision 5
  Found Google Analytics SDK, revision 2
  Found Google Web Driver, revision 2
Fetching URL: http://dl.htcdev.com/sdk/addon.xml
Validate XML: http://dl.htcdev.com/sdk/addon.xml
Parse XML:    http://dl.htcdev.com/sdk/addon.xml
  Found OpenSense SDK for Tablets, Android API 12, revision 2
  Found OpenSense SDK for Phones, Android API 10, revision 2
Fetching URL: http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/android/addon.xml
Validate XML: http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/android/addon.xml
Parse XML:    http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/android/addon.xml
  Found Intel Atom x86 System Image, Android API 10, revision 1
  Found Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager, revision 1
Fetching URL: http://www.echobykyocera.com/download/echo_repository.xml
Validate XML: http://www.echobykyocera.com/download/echo_repository.xml
Parse XML:    http://www.echobykyocera.com/download/echo_repository.xml
  Found Dual Screen APIs, Android API 8, revision 1
  Found Dual Screen APIs, Android API 10, revision 1
Fetching URL: http://developer.lgmobile.com/sdk/android/repository.xml
Validate XML: http://developer.lgmobile.com/sdk/android/repository.xml
Parse XML:    http://developer.lgmobile.com/sdk/android/repository.xml
  Found Real3D, Android API 10, revision 2
  Found Real3D, Android API 8, revision 1
Fetching URL: http://android-sdk-addons.motodevupdate.com/addons.xml
Validate XML: http://android-sdk-addons.motodevupdate.com/addons.xml
Parse XML:    http://android-sdk-addons.motodevupdate.com/addons.xml
  Found ADMIRAL, Android API 10, revision 5
  Found ATRIX2, Android API 10, revision 1
  Found Droid4, Android API 10, revision 2
  Found DroidRAZR, Android API 10, revision 5
  Found MT917, Android API 10, revision 1
  Found MotorolaPro+, Android API 10, revision 2
  Found XOOM2, Android API 13, revision 2
  Found XOOM2ME, Android API 13, revision 2
  Found XT882, Android API 10, revision 2
  Found XT928, Android API 10, revision 1
  Found defy+, Android API 10, revision 1
  Found Bionic, Android API 10, revision 2
  Found MT870, Android API 10, revision 2
  Found PHOTON, Android API 10, revision 1
  Found XOOM, Android API 11, revision 2
Fetching URL: http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/android/repository/repository.xml
Validate XML: http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/android/repository/repository.xml
Parse XML:    http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/android/repository/repository.xml
  Found GALAXY Tab, Android API 8, revision 1
Fetching URL: http://developer.sonymobile.com/edk/android/repository.xml
Validate XML: http://developer.sonymobile.com/edk/android/repository.xml
Parse XML:    http://developer.sonymobile.com/edk/android/repository.xml
  Found Sony Xperia Extensions EDK 2.0, Android API 10, revision 2
Done loading packages.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-2.3.3_r02-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Samples for SDK API 10, revision 1
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\samples-2.3.3_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Google USB Driver, revision 4
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\usb_driver_r04-windows.zip (Access is denied)
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 10, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'OpenSense SDK for Phones, Android API 10, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel Atom x86 System Image, Android API 10, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Dual Screen APIs, Android API 10, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Real3D, Android API 10, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ADMIRAL, Android API 10, revision 5'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ATRIX2, Android API 10, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Bionic, Android API 10, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'defy+, Android API 10, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Droid4, Android API 10, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'DroidRAZR, Android API 10, revision 5'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'MotorolaPro+, Android API 10, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'MT870, Android API 10, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'MT917, Android API 10, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'PHOTON, Android API 10, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'XT882, Android API 10, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'XT928, Android API 10, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Sony Xperia Extensions EDK 2.0, Android API 10, revision 2'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-2.3.3_r02-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Downloading Samples for SDK API 10, revision 1
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\samples-2.3.3_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

I noticed that there was a few reference to:"File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\samples-2.3.3_r01-linux.zip (Access is denied)" or some sort of linux.zip thing but I am using a Windows 7 instead of a Linux OS.

Why would Linux be brought up ? Wouldn't it be obvious that linux binaries not work on Windows ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to run it as admin since you get `Access is denied` errors. Windows (> Vista afaik) does not allow to write to `C:\Program Files (x86)\` without that.